# Компиляция LESS файлов в Webstorm

Tags: css, less, webstorm

Подскажите пожалуйста!!! Как можно сделать чтобы компилировались в CSS только определенные файлы созданные мной?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете настроить соответствующий Scope (Settings/Appearance & Behavior/Scopes), включающий только созданные Вами файлы, и выбрать этот Scope в качестве File Watcher Scope - тогда компиляция будет запускаться только при редактировании выбранных файлов, а не для всех LESS файлов в проекте

Comment: По подробнее можно пожалуйста?

Comment: а каких именно подробностей не хватает? интерфейс настройки scopes вообще довольно прозрачен